# CloudFormation WaitCondition requires public access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation script which deploys a single instance in the VPC. 
The script only works when the instance has a public IP. Without a public IP address, the template deployment fails at WaitCondition stage. I guess thats because the WaitCondition requires instance has access to the Internet?

Instead of assigning a public IP, will it work if I set the proxy address on the server? So the instance access the Internet via web proxy. If that's the case, what's the web URLs need to be whitelisted on the proxy? and can I add the add proxy address command in the userdata?

Below is my template:

```
  "Mappings": {
    "AWSRegion2AMI": {
      "ap-southeast-2": {
        "Windows2008r2": "ami-27b39a44",
        "Windows2012r2": "ami-83b198e0"
      }
    }

  },

  "Resources": {
    "DomainController": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
          "config": {
            "files": {
              "c:\\cfn\\cfn-hup.conf": {
                "content": {
                  "Fn::Join": ["", [
                    "[main]\n",
                    "stack=", {
                      "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                    }, "\n",
                    "region=", {
                      "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                    }, "\n"
                  ]]
                }
              },

              "c:\\cfn\\hooks.d\\cfn-auto-reloader.conf": {
                "content": {
                  "Fn::Join": ["", [
                    "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
                    "triggers=post.update\n",
                    "path=Resources.DomainController.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                    "action=cfn-init.exe -v -s ", {
                      "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                    },
                    " -r DomainController",
                    " --region ", {
                      "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                    }, "\n"
                  ]]
                }
              },

              "C:\\cfn\\RunCommand.bat": {
                "content": "%~1\nIF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 10 ( exit /b 1 ) else ( exit /b 0 )"
              }
            },

            "commands": {
              "1-run-dcpromo": {
                "command": {
                  "Fn::Join": ["", [
                    "C:\\cfn\\RunCommand.bat \"dcpromo /unattend  /ReplicaOrNewDomain:Domain  /NewDomain:Forest  /NewDomainDNSName:", {
                      "Ref": "DomainDNSName"
                    },
                    "  /ForestLevel:4 /DomainNetbiosName:", {
                      "Ref": "DomainNetBIOSName"
                    },
                    " /DomainLevel:4  /InstallDNS:Yes  /ConfirmGc:Yes  /CreateDNSDelegation:No  /DatabasePath:\"C:\\Windows\\NTDS\"  /LogPath:\"C:\\Windows\\NTDS\"  /SYSVOLPath:\"C:\\Windows\\SYSVOL\" /SafeModeAdminPassword=", {
                      "Ref": "RestoreModePassword"
                    },
                    " /RebootOnCompletion:Yes\""
                  ]]
                },
                "waitAfterCompletion": "forever"
              },
              "2-signal-success": {
                "command": {
                  "Fn::Join": ["", [
                    "cfn-signal.exe -e 0 \"", {
                      "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Ref": "DomainControllerWaitHandle"
                      }
                    }, "\""
                  ]]
                }
              }
            },

            "services": {
              "windows": {
                "cfn-hup": {
                  "enabled": "true",
                  "ensureRunning": "true",
                  "files": ["c:\\cfn\\cfn-hup.conf", "c:\\cfn\\hooks.d\\cfn-auto-reloader.conf"]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },

      "Properties": {
        "ImageId": {
          "Fn::FindInMap": ["AWSRegion2AMI", {
            "Ref": "AWS::Region"
          }, "Windows2008r2"]
        },
        "InstanceType": {
          "Ref": "InstanceType"
        },
        "NetworkInterfaces": [{
          "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "false",
          "DeviceIndex": "0",
          "SubnetId": {
            "Ref": "SubnetId"
          }
        }],

        "KeyName": {
          "Ref": "KeyName"
        },

        "UserData": {
          "Fn::Base64": {
            "Fn::Join": ["", [
              "<script>\n",

              "cfn-init.exe -v -s ", {
                "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
              },
              " -r DomainController ",
              " --region ", {
                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
              }, "\n",

              "</script>"
            ]]
          }
        }
      }
    },

    "DomainControllerWaitCondition": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition",
      "DependsOn": "DomainController",
      "Properties": {
        "Handle": {
          "Ref": "DomainControllerWaitHandle"
        },
        "Timeout": "1500"
      }
    },

    "DomainControllerWaitHandle": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the proxy by adding on of those parameters to cfn-signal.exe:

```
--http-proxy
An HTTP proxy (non-SSL). Use the following format: http://user:password@host:port

--https-proxy
An HTTPS proxy. Use the following format: https://user:password@host:port
```

The signal is sent to an S3 Bucket. You can whitelist something like:

```
https://cloudformation-waitcondition-*.s3.amazonaws.com
```

Note: You can also use the S3 VPC endpoint feature to allow resources inside private subnets to access S3. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html